# How to turn on/off airplane mode in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mobile-data

How to turn on/off airplane mode in Xamarin.Forms for android and ios?

Comment: You mean you want to set/unset that from your app? Not possible.

Comment: Imagine you were allowed to do this, what a nasty security hole that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @Patrick Hofman and @DavidG said.You could not turn on/off airplane mode by code in your project . However , you can open the setting page of system in Forms by using **Dependency Service** and let user turn on/off airplane mode manual.

> in Forms,add a new interface

```
public interface ISettingsService
{
  void OpenSettings();
}
```

> in iOS

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenSettingsImplement))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class OpenSettingsImplement : ISettingsService
    {
        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            var url = new NSUrl($"App-Prefs:");
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

`App-Prefs:` is private api in iOS. So if you want to upload it to app store , it will may been rejected by the store .

> in Android

```
using Android.Content;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenSettingsImplement))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class OpenSettingsImplement : ISettingsService
    {
        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            Intent intentOpenSettings = new Intent();
            intentOpenSettings.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionAirplaneModeSettings);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentOpenSettings);
        }
    }
}
```